# google app engine dev_appserver.py file not found

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

i have searched through many python issues and none seem to help me with mine or i just don't understand it enough to resolve the issue. basically i am trying to learn python so in the process on my mac i have installed serveral versions and had many version issues which so far i have been able to resolve by looking up ways to resolve it. however i am now at a part in head first python that needs to install google app engine the book is a good bit out of date so i installed the latest app engine and made the symbolic links but when i run the application the browser is greyed out. i have seen many references to dev_appserver.py in my long search to resolve this. i cannot my this file anywhere on my machine so i presume i have an issue with my install of python2.7 i have re-installed and then uninstalled and re-installed python 2.7 over and over but still cannot find the dev_appserver.py file . does anyone have a concrete way to ensure dev_appserver.py will be installed. thanks in advance from a seriously frustrated python beginner.

Comment: dev_appserver.py comes from the appengine SDK. It's not part of python.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

Comment: ok thanks Paul but i have also installed and uninstalled app engine several times , the only difference i notice on my mac when installing it does not prompt me for the symlinks, i did though run it in appengine interface but still no joy.

Comment: very strange literally 2 seconds after adding my comment i opened app engine and it had a message about runtime then popped up looking for symlinks and bang all sorted, odd the way it didnt do this before as i have restarted app engine and my mac about 10 times since i got this issue.

Answer (score 1):

On my PC it is found under this directory:

C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine

I would assume that on Apple OS it will be similar based on where you decided to install the Cloud SDK.